# Creating a zip archive from memory stream in .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, memorystream, sharpziplib

I'm trying to create a zip archive from memory stream and when I download it from my API on the web-side it tells me the archive is corrupt when I try to open it (and not much else, the download itself is successful).

This is the code I use for generating the zip-archive:

```
    public byte[] ZipFiles(IEnumerable<FileContentResult> filesToZip)
    {
        var outputMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputMemoryStream);

        zipStream.SetLevel(3);

        foreach (var fileToZip in filesToZip)
        {
            var inputMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileToZip.FileContents);
            var zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileToZip.FileDownloadName);
            zipEntry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

            zipStream.PutNextEntry(zipEntry);
            StreamUtils.Copy(inputMemoryStream, zipStream, new byte[4096]);
            zipStream.CloseEntry();
        }

        zipStream.IsStreamOwner = false;
        zipStream.Close();

        outputMemoryStream.Position = 0;

        return outputMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }
```

It returns the zip file as a byte array, which is then put into another filecontentresult before being returned from the API (I've tried setting contenttype to both `application/octet-stream` and `application/zip`). I've seen and tried a huge amount of different solutions here on stackoverflow, but all of them seem to fail when trying to open the downloaded file. I'm using SharpZipLib. Anyone got any pointers?

Edit/new info:
After further testing/debugging, it seems like the zip file itself is okay. If I save it to the server disk I'm able to open/unpack the files. However, the action of putting it into a filecontentresult and returning it from the controller & downloading it on a client seems to break it. The file name is okay, with a .zip extension, and as mentioned I've tried both `application/octet-stream` and `application/zip` as contenttype (I think the second is is correct to use). We do already return and download other files from the API just fine, it's just zip-files that are somehow not working correctly here.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, `outputMemoryStream.Position = 0` is not enough since you don’t have a reference of the initial position and the current one. So, before the return of the function, you have to move the pointer of the `memorystream` at the very start. For that, replace `outputMemoryStream.Position = 0` with `outputMemoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`.